# How to cut Audio file using time range in android?

Tags: android

I am able to cut audio file using FIleInputStream and FileOutputStram in android. But crop audio not playing. I want to cut audio file on giving start time and end time.

Answer (score 1):

The only interesting and useful library I have found for audio editing is Ringdroid (available here http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/).

You can check the source code in order to get some insights on how to do what you want.

Hope this helps for now!

Comment: As I have seen provided link but there was only apk file no library or source code was available. Can you give full example or code for same.

Comment: Click on source then get a copy of repository by svn checkout

Comment: Or if u want to do manually then goto browse under source section

Comment: any one please tell me how to use ringdroid and where is the main code of trimming audio in this source code